# Why a zero length path does not find match when using label?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query:

`MATCH at = (root)<-[:ATTRIBUTE_OF*0..1]-() RETURN at;`

This return 3 nodes, but:

`MATCH at = (root)<-[:ATTRIBUTE_OF*0..1]-(:Attribute) RETURN at;`

returns zero nodes.

What's the difference, isn't supossed to be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite the same.

In your first query, it will match to a `root` node (any node really), and each `at` path will at least include the node itself (with no relationships, for the *0 portion), but you'll also get a path back for each :ATTRIBUTE_OF relationship that exists on the node (for the *1 portion).

The second query is similar, but it requires that the node at the end is an :Attribute node. For the *0 cases, `root` and the other node are the same (traversing 0 relationships means your start and end node are the same), so it would require that `root` is an :Attribute node.

Since you're not getting results back, we could conclude that there are no :Attribute nodes in your graph.

If it helps, read the query from the other direction: starting at an :Attribute node, return all :ATTRIBUTE_OF relationships of length 0 or 1 to a node (which we'll address as `root`) and return the paths found.